# Simple float array compress/deflate to gz file example?

Tags: c++, zlib

I have a float array I calculate:
float my_floatarray[32][256][256][3];

What I want to do is to compress/deflate this as small as possible to a gz file using zlib.

I compiled zlib from source already, but was trying to a find a simple example that did this. The documentation on the website was not entirely straightfoward

Comment: How do you intend to serialize your floats? Does machine portability matter?

Comment: mostly windows, but no I don't care much about machine portability, its for a basic example to speed up io. Thanks!

Comment: Never used it myself, but this webpage looks useful, if you haven't seen it: http://www.zlib.net/zlib_how.html

Comment: There's a good example in `def()` [here](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/zpipe.c). If you use a stream instead of a FILE* for your output, make sure you open it in binary mode (e.g. `std::ofstream fout("filename.gz", std::ios::binary | std::ios::trunc);`).

Comment: I looked at the def example, but if the float array is already defined in memory since I calculate it on the fly, how do I replace that with the source FILE

Comment: Also if I am going between my windows laptop and desktop .. would I have to worry about shifting the floats to make them compatible based on the first comment by Cameron?

Comment: "as small as possible" is a rather vague metric. You could simply compress the list of numbers as is, but you would likely achieve better compression by transforming the data in various ways first - delta coding, Fourier or other transforms - like jpeg, mpeg, ogg/vorbis, etc... It's a little unclear how much effort you really want to go to here. If you really just want to compress the array as-is, you only need to compress the single block of 32*256*256*3*sizeof(float) bytes...